# Deployed pipeline component crashes VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, btdf, custom-pipeline-component

I am using the BizTalk Deployment Framework (BTDF) to deploy my project and within that project is a pipeline component.  The component appears to deploy fine, the dll in the Pipeline Components folder of the BizTalk install.  However it does not show in the toolbox and any attempt to reset the toolbox crashes VS2010 which will not restart until the component has been removed ...

Anyone else come across something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the pipeline component wizard and the length of namespaces, class names etc.  Shortening these seems to have removed the issue.